# how to add stimulsoft js to webpack angular 5 (framework jhipster)

Tags: angular, webpack, jhipster

I'm using jhipster in my project.
in this project we use angular 5 for ui.
for my report use stimulsoft and I need to add 
report.js
and viewer.js of to my project but after add this to vendor.ts show the below error:

```
ERROR in ./src/main/webapp/content/plugins/stimulsoft/stimulsoft.reports.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './ods' in


'D:\khosroshahi\project\boursamnew2\src\main\webapp\content\plugins\stimulsoft'
 @ ./src/main/webapp/content/plugins/stimulsoft/stimulsoft.reports.js 129:100617-100636
 @ ./src/main/webapp/app/vendor.ts
 @ ./src/main/webapp/app/app.module.ts
 @ ./src/main/webapp/app/app.main.ts
 @ multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://localhost:9060 webpack/hot/dev-server ./src/main/webapp/app/app.main

ERROR in ./node_modules/tedious/lib/sender.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'dgram' in 'D:\khosroshahi\project\boursamnew2\node_modules\tedious\lib'
 @ ./node_modules/tedious/lib/sender.js 13:12-28
 @ ./node_modules/tedious/lib/instance-lookup.js
 @ ./node_modules/tedious/lib/connection.js
 @ ./node_modules/tedious/lib/tedious.js
 @ ./node_modules/mssql/lib/tedious.js
 @ ./node_modules/mssql/index.js
 @ ./src/main/webapp/content/plugins/stimulsoft/stimulsoft.reports.js
 @ ./src/main/webapp/app/vendor.ts
 @ ./src/main/webapp/app/app.module.ts
 @ ./src/main/webapp/app/app.main.ts
 @ multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://localhost:9060 webpack/hot/dev-server ./src/main/webapp/app/app.main

ERROR in ./node_modules/pg/lib/connection-parameters.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'dns' in 'D:\khosroshahi\project\boursamnew2\node_modules\pg\lib'
 @ ./node_modules/pg/lib/connection-parameters.js 2:10-24
 @ ./node_modules/pg/lib/native/index.js
 @ ./node_modules/pg/lib/index.js
 @ ./src/main/webapp/content/plugins/stimulsoft/stimulsoft.reports.js
 @ ./src/main/webapp/app/vendor.ts
 @ ./src/main/webapp/app/app.module.ts
 @ ./src/main/webapp/app/app.main.ts
 @ multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://localhost:9060 webpack/hot/dev-server ./src/main/webapp/app/app.main

ERROR in ./node_modules/tedious/lib/sender.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'dns' in 'D:\khosroshahi\project\boursamnew2\node_modules\tedious\lib'
 @ ./node_modules/tedious/lib/sender.js 14:10-24
 @ ./node_modules/tedious/lib/instance-lookup.js
 @ ./node_modules/tedious/lib/connection.js
 @ ./node_modules/tedious/lib/tedious.js
 @ ./node_modules/mssql/lib/tedious.js
 @ ./node_modules/mssql/index.js
 @ ./src/main/webapp/content/plugins/stimulsoft/stimulsoft.reports.js
 @ ./src/main/webapp/app/vendor.ts
 @ ./src/main/webapp/app/app.module.ts
 @ ./src/main/webapp/app/app.main.ts
 @ multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://localhost:9060 webpack/hot/dev-server ./src/main/webapp/app/app.main

ERROR in ./node_modules/tedious/lib/connector.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'dns' in 'D:\khosroshahi\project\boursamnew2\node_modules\tedious\lib'
 @ ./node_modules/tedious/lib/connector.js 18:10-24
 @ ./node_modules/tedious/lib/connection.js
 @ ./node_modules/tedious/lib/tedious.js
 @ ./node_modules/mssql/lib/tedious.js
 @ ./node_modules/mssql/index.js
 @ ./src/main/webapp/content/plugins/stimulsoft/stimulsoft.reports.js
 @ ./src/main/webapp/app/vendor.ts
 @ ./src/main/webapp/app/app.module.ts
 @ ./src/main/webapp/app/app.main.ts
 @ multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://localhost:9060 webpack/hot/dev-server ./src/main/webapp/app/app.main

ERROR in ./node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/sequences/Query.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in 'D:\khosroshahi\project\boursamnew2\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\sequences'
 @ ./node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/sequences/Query.js 6:19-32
 @ ./node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js
 @ ./node_modules/mysql/index.js
 @ ./src/main/webapp/content/plugins/stimulsoft/stimulsoft.reports.js
 @ ./src/main/webapp/app/vendor.ts
 @ ./src/main/webapp/app/app.module.ts
 @ ./src/main/webapp/app/app.main.ts
 @ multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://localhost:9060 webpack/hot/dev-server ./src/main/webapp/app/app.main

ERROR in ./node_modules/node-firebird/lib/messages.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in 'D:\khosroshahi\project\boursamnew2\node_modules\node-firebird\lib'
 @ ./node_modules/node-firebird/lib/messages.js 1:9-22
 @ ./node_modules/node-firebird/lib/index.js
 @ ./src/main/webapp/content/plugins/stimulsoft/stimulsoft.reports.js
 @ ./src/main/webapp/app/vendor.ts
 @ ./src/main/webapp/app/app.module.ts
 @ ./src/main/webapp/app/app.main.ts
 @ multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://localhost:9060 webpack/hot/dev-server ./src/main/webapp/app/app.main

ERROR in ./node_modules/pgpass/lib/index.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in 'D:\khosroshahi\project\boursamnew2\node_modules\pgpass\lib'
 @ ./node_modules/pgpass/lib/index.js 4:9-22
 @ ./node_modules/pg/lib/client.js
 @ ./node_modules/pg/lib/index.js
 @ ./src/main/webapp/content/plugins/stimulsoft/stimulsoft.reports.js
 @ ./src/main/webapp/app/vendor.ts
 @ ./src/main/webapp/app/app.module.ts
 @ ./src/main/webapp/app/app.main.ts
 @ multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://localhost:9060 webpack/hot/dev-server ./src/main/webapp/app/app.main

ERROR in ./src/main/webapp/content/plugins/stimulsoft/stimulsoft.reports.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in 'D:\khosroshahi\project\boursamnew2\src\main\webapp\content\plugins\stimulsoft'
 @ ./src/main/webapp/content/plugins/stimulsoft/stimulsoft.reports.js 129:137288-137301 133:64066-64079 133:64725-64738 133:65408-65421 133:65942-65955
 @ ./src/main/webapp/app/vendor.ts
 @ ./src/main/webapp/app/app.module.ts
 @ ./src/main/webapp/app/app.main.ts
 @ multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://localhost:9060 webpack/hot/dev-server ./src/main/webapp/app/app.main

ERROR in ./node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'net' in 'D:\khosroshahi\project\boursamnew2\node_modules\mysql\lib'
 @ ./node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js 3:23-37
 @ ./node_modules/mysql/index.js
 @ ./src/main/webapp/content/plugins/stimulsoft/stimulsoft.reports.js
 @ ./src/main/webapp/app/vendor.ts
 @ ./src/main/webapp/app/app.module.ts
 @ ./src/main/webapp/app/app.main.ts
 @ multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://localhost:9060 webpack/hot/dev-server ./src/main/webapp/app/app.main

ERROR in ./node_modules/node-firebird/lib/index.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'net' in 'D:\khosroshahi\project\boursamnew2\node_modules\node-firebird\lib'
 @ ./node_modules/node-firebird/lib/index.js 2:10-24
 @ ./src/main/webapp/content/plugins/stimulsoft/stimulsoft.reports.js
 @ ./src/main/webapp/app/vendor.ts
 @ ./src/main/webapp/app/app.module.ts
 @ ./src/main/webapp/app/app.main.ts
 @ multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://localhost:9060 webpack/hot/dev-server ./src/main/webapp/app/app.main

ERROR in ./node_modules/pg/lib/connection.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'net' in 'D:\khosroshahi\project\boursamnew2\node_modules\pg\lib'
 @ ./node_modules/pg/lib/connection.js 1:10-24
 @ ./node_modules/pg/lib/index.js
 @ ./src/main/webapp/content/plugins/stimulsoft/stimulsoft.reports.js
 @ ./src/main/webapp/app/vendor.ts
 @ ./src/main/webapp/app/app.module.ts
 @ ./src/main/webapp/app/app.main.ts
 @ multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://localhost:9060 webpack/hot/dev-server ./src/main/webapp/app/app.main

ERROR in ./node_modules/tedious/lib/connector.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'net' in 'D:\khosroshahi\project\boursamnew2\node_modules\tedious\lib'
 @ ./node_modules/tedious/lib/connector.js 17:10-24
 @ ./node_modules/tedious/lib/connection.js
 @ ./node_modules/tedious/lib/tedious.js
 @ ./node_modules/mssql/lib/tedious.js
 @ ./node_modules/mssql/index.js
 @ ./src/main/webapp/content/plugins/stimulsoft/stimulsoft.reports.js
 @ ./src/main/webapp/app/vendor.ts
 @ ./src/main/webapp/app/app.module.ts
 @ ./src/main/webapp/app/app.main.ts
 @ multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://localhost:9060 webpack/hot/dev-server ./src/main/webapp/app/app.main

ERROR in ./node_modules/tedious/lib/sender.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'net' in
'D:\khosroshahi\project\boursamnew2\node_modules\tedious\lib'
  @ ./node_modules/tedious/lib/sender.js 15:10-24
  @ ./node_modules/tedious/lib/instance-lookup.js
 @ ./node_modules/tedious/lib/connection.js
 @ ./node_modules/tedious/lib/tedious.js
 @ ./node_modules/mssql/lib/tedious.js
 @ ./node_modules/mssql/index.js
 @ ./src/main/webapp/content/plugins/stimulsoft/stimulsoft.reports.js
 @ ./src/main/webapp/app/vendor.ts
 @ ./src/main/webapp/app/app.module.ts
 @ ./src/main/webapp/app/app.main.ts
 @ multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://localhost:9060 webpack/hot/dev-server ./src/main/webapp/app/app.main

ERROR in ./node_modules/pg/lib/native/index.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'pg-native' in 'D:\khosroshahi\project\boursamnew2\node_modules\pg\lib\native'
 @ ./node_modules/pg/lib/native/index.js 1:13-33
 @ ./node_modules/pg/lib/index.js
 @ ./src/main/webapp/content/plugins/stimulsoft/stimulsoft.reports.js
 @ ./src/main/webapp/app/vendor.ts
 @ ./src/main/webapp/app/app.module.ts
 @ ./src/main/webapp/app/app.main.ts
 @ multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://localhost:9060 webpack/hot/dev-server ./src/main/webapp/app/app.main

ERROR in ./node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'tls' in 'D:\khosroshahi\project\boursamnew2\node_modules\mysql\lib'
 @ ./node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js 4:23-37
 @ ./node_modules/mysql/index.js
 @ ./src/main/webapp/content/plugins/stimulsoft/stimulsoft.reports.js
 @ ./src/main/webapp/app/vendor.ts
 @ ./src/main/webapp/app/app.module.ts
 @ ./src/main/webapp/app/app.main.ts
 @ multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://localhost:9060 webpack/hot/dev-server ./src/main/webapp/app/app.main

ERROR in ./node_modules/pg/lib/connection.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'tls' in 'D:\khosroshahi\project\boursamnew2\node_modules\pg\lib'
 @ ./node_modules/pg/lib/connection.js 78:14-28
 @ ./node_modules/pg/lib/index.js
 @ ./src/main/webapp/content/plugins/stimulsoft/stimulsoft.reports.js
 @ ./src/main/webapp/app/vendor.ts
 @ ./src/main/webapp/app/app.module.ts
 @ ./src/main/webapp/app/app.main.ts
 @ multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://localhost:9060 webpack/hot/dev-server ./src/main/webapp/app/app.main

ERROR in ./node_modules/tedious/lib/message-io.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'tls' in 'D:\khosroshahi\project\boursamnew2\node_modules\tedious\lib'
 @ ./node_modules/tedious/lib/message-io.js 27:10-24
 @ ./node_modules/tedious/lib/connection.js
 @ ./node_modules/tedious/lib/tedious.js
 @ ./node_modules/mssql/lib/tedious.js
 @ ./node_modules/mssql/index.js
 @ ./src/main/webapp/content/plugins/stimulsoft/stimulsoft.reports.js
 @ ./src/main/webapp/app/vendor.ts
 @ ./src/main/webapp/app/app.module.ts
 @ ./src/main/webapp/app/app.main.ts
 @ multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://localhost:9060 webpack/hot/dev-server ./src/main/webapp/app/app.main
```

i use yarn and My pakage.json is:

```
 {
  "name": "gwadmin",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "description": "Description for gwadmin",
  "private": true,
  "license": "UNLICENSED",
  "cacheDirectories": [
    "node_modules"
  ],
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/cdk": "5.2.0",
    "@angular/common": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/core": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/http": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/material": "5.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/router": "^5.2.0",
    "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "1.0.0-beta.7",
    "@types/lodash": "4.14.117",
    "angular-tree-component": "^7.0.1",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "file-saver": "^1.3.3",
    "font-awesome": "4.7.0",
    "jalali-moment": "3.1.1",
    "jquery": "3.2.1",
    "material-icon-font": "^3.0.1",
    "ng-jhipster": "0.3.4",
    "ngx-cookie": "2.0.1",
    "ngx-image-cropper": "0.1.14",
    "ngx-infinite-scroll": "0.5.1",
    "ngx-loading": "^1.0.14",
    "ngx-progressbar": "^2.1.1",
    "ngx-toastr": "^8.0.0",
    "ngx-webstorage": "2.0.1",
    "reflect-metadata": "0.1.10",
    "rxjs": "^5.5.6",
    "sockjs-client": "1.1.4",
    "stimulsoft-reports-js": "2018.3.2",
    "swagger-ui": "2.2.10",
    "tether": "1.4.0",
    "underscore": "1.8.3",
    "webstomp-client": "1.0.6",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.19"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "~1.7.4",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/language-service": "^5.2.0",
    "@ngtools/webpack": "1.8.5",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.8.3",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.2",
    "@types/node": "~6.0.60",
    "angular2-template-loader": "0.6.2",
    "awesome-typescript-loader": "3.2.2",
    "browser-sync": "2.18.13",
    "browser-sync-webpack-plugin": "1.2.0",
    "codelyzer": "^4.0.1",
    "copy-webpack-plugin": "4.2.3",
    "css-loader": "0.28.4",
    "exports-loader": "0.6.4",
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "3.0.2",
    "file-loader": "1.1.5",
    "generator-jhipster": "4.13.0",
    "html-loader": "0.5.0",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "2.30.1",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.8.0",
    "jasmine-reporters": "2.2.1",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~2.0.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage": "1.1.1",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^1.2.1",
    "karma-intl-shim": "1.0.3",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "karma-junit-reporter": "1.2.0",
    "karma-notify-reporter": "1.0.1",
    "karma-phantomjs-launcher": "1.0.4",
    "karma-remap-istanbul": "0.6.0",
    "karma-sourcemap-loader": "0.3.7",
    "karma-webpack": "2.0.4",
    "merge-jsons-webpack-plugin": "1.0.11",
    "node-sass": "4.5.3",
    "phantomjs-prebuilt": "2.1.16",
    "postcss-loader": "2.0.9",
    "protractor": "~5.1.2",
    "protractor-jasmine2-screenshot-reporter": "0.4.0",
    "proxy-middleware": "0.15.0",
    "rimraf": "2.6.1",
    "sass-loader": "6.0.6",
    "script-loader": "^0.7.2",
    "sourcemap-istanbul-instrumenter-loader": "0.2.0",
    "string-replace-webpack-plugin": "0.1.3",
    "style-loader": "0.18.2",
    "to-string-loader": "1.1.5",
    "ts-node": "~4.1.0",
    "tslint": "~5.9.1",
    "tslint-loader": "3.5.3",
    "typescript": "~2.5.3",
    "uglifyjs-webpack-plugin": "1.1.2",
    "web-app-manifest-loader": "0.1.1",
    "webpack": "^3.12.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "2.9.5",
    "webpack-merge": "4.1.1",
    "webpack-notifier": "1.5.0",
    "webpack-visualizer-plugin": "0.1.11",
    "workbox-webpack-plugin": "2.1.2",
    "write-file-webpack-plugin": "4.1.0",
    "xml2js": "0.4.17"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": ">=6.9.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "lint": "tslint --project './tsconfig.json' -e 'node_modules/**'",
    "lint:fix": "yarn run lint -- --fix",
    "ngc": "ngc -p tsconfig-aot.json",
    "cleanup": "rimraf target/{aot,www}",
    "clean-www": "rimraf target//www/app/{src,target/}",
    "start": "yarn run webpack:dev",
    "serve": "yarn run start",
    "build": "yarn run webpack:prod",
    "test": "yarn run lint && karma start src/test/javascript/karma.conf.js",
    "test:watch": "yarn test -- --watch",
    "webpack:dev": "yarn run webpack-dev-server -- --config webpack/webpack.dev.js --progress --inline --hot --profile --port=9060 --watch-content-base",
    "webpack:build:main": "yarn run webpack -- --config webpack/webpack.dev.js --progress --profile",
    "webpack:build": "yarn run cleanup && yarn run webpack:build:main",
    "webpack:prod:main": "yarn run webpack -- --config webpack/webpack.prod.js --progress --profile",
    "webpack:prod": "yarn run cleanup && yarn run webpack:prod:main && yarn run clean-www",
    "webpack:test": "yarn run test",
    "webpack-dev-server": "node --max_old_space_size=4096 node_modules/webpack-dev-server/bin/webpack-dev-server.js",
    "webpack": "node --max_old_space_size=4096 node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js",
    "e2e": "protractor src/test/javascript/protractor.conf.js",
    "postinstall": "webdriver-manager update && node node_modules/phantomjs-prebuilt/install.js"
  }
}
```

I use webpack and my webpack.dev.js is:

```
    const webpack = require('webpack');
const writeFilePlugin = require('write-file-webpack-plugin');
const webpackMerge = require('webpack-merge');
const BrowserSyncPlugin = require('browser-sync-webpack-plugin');
const WebpackNotifierPlugin = require('webpack-notifier');
const path = require('path');

const utils = require('./utils.js');
const commonConfig = require('./webpack.common.js');

const ENV = 'development';

module.exports = webpackMerge(commonConfig({ env: ENV }), {
    devtool: 'eval-source-map',
    devServer: {
        contentBase: './target/www',
        proxy: [{
            context: [
                '/uaa',
                /* jhipster-needle-add-entity-to-webpack - JHipster will add entity api paths here */
                '/api',
                '/management',
                '/swagger-resources',
                '/v2/api-docs',
                '/h2-console',
                '/auth'
            ],
            target: 'http://127.0.0.1:8056',
            secure: false
        },{
            context: [
                '/websocket'
            ],
            target: 'ws://127.0.0.1:8056',
            ws: true
        }],
        watchOptions: {
            ignored: /node_modules/
        }
    },
    entry: {
        polyfills: './src/main/webapp/app/polyfills',
        global: './src/main/webapp/content/scss/global.scss',
        main: './src/main/webapp/app/app.main'
    },
    output: {
        path: utils.root('target/www'),
        filename: 'app/[name].bundle.js',
        chunkFilename: 'app/[id].chunk.js'
    },
    module: {
        rules: [{
            test: /\.ts$/,
            enforce: 'pre',
            loaders: 'tslint-loader',
            exclude: ['node_modules', new RegExp('reflect-metadata\\' + path.sep + 'Reflect\\.ts')]
        },
        {
            test: /\.ts$/,
            loaders: [
                'angular2-template-loader',
                'awesome-typescript-loader'
            ],
            exclude: ['node_modules/generator-jhipster']
        },
        {
            test: /\.scss$/,
            loaders: ['to-string-loader', 'css-loader', 'sass-loader'],
            exclude: /(vendor\.scss|global\.scss)/
        },
            {
                test: /\.exec\.js$/,
                use: [ 'script-loader' ]
            }
        ,
        {
            test: /(vendor\.scss|global\.scss)/,
            loaders: ['style-loader', 'css-loader', 'postcss-loader', 'sass-loader']
        },
        {
            test: /\.css$/,
            loaders: ['to-string-loader', 'css-loader'],
            exclude: /(vendor\.css|global\.css)/
        },
        {
            test: /(vendor\.css|global\.css)/,
            loaders: ['style-loader', 'css-loader']
        }]
    },
    plugins: [
        new BrowserSyncPlugin({
            host: 'localhost',
            port: 9000,
            proxy: {
                target: 'http://localhost:9060',
                ws: true
            }
        }, {
            reload: false
        }),
        new webpack.NoEmitOnErrorsPlugin(),
        new webpack.NamedModulesPlugin(),
        new writeFilePlugin(),
        new webpack.WatchIgnorePlugin([
            utils.root('src/test'),
        ]),
        new WebpackNotifierPlugin({
            title: 'JHipster',
            contentImage: path.join(__dirname, 'logo-jhipster.png')
        })
    ]
});
```

anyone help me in this problem??

Comment: Don't put your dependencies in src\main\webapp\content,  stimulsoft is an npm module that your referenced from package.json, see your project README.md for an example on how to manage dependencies (vendor.ts, ...)

Comment: thank you  @GaëlMarziou . but I can't add this js file to my project. I installed Stimulsoft to resolve this problem and I don't use it. I read README.md and try to import js file to vendor.ts.I have problem with add the stimulsoft.report.js to vendor.ts right now. whereas,I add this js to anular-cli with no problem.

Comment: jhipster does not supoort fully angular cli, in particular adding dependencies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add follow code in web pack **confg file**

```
new CopyWebpackPlugin([
  {
    from: 'assets/stimulsoft',
    to: 'assets/stimulsoft/',
    toType: 'dir'
  }
])
```

Then add reference to files in **index.html**

```html
  <link href="assets/stimulsoft/stimulsoft.viewer.office2013.whiteblue.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/stimulsoft/stimulsoft.reports.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/stimulsoft/stimulsoft.viewer.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/stimulsoft/stimulsoft.designer.js"></script>
```

Now you can use in your *component* like below code

```
declare var Stimulsoft: any;

@Component({
  templateUrl: './reportdesignprint.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./reportdesignprint.component.css'],
})
export class ReportDesignPrintComponent implements OnDestroy, OnInit {

  constructor(private _reportSubjectService: ReportSubjectService, private _route: ActivatedRoute, private _router: Router) {

  }
  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.load();
  }
  ngOnDestroy(): void {

  }
  load() {
    var report = new Stimulsoft.Report.StiReport();
    // report.loadFile("SimpleList.mrt");
    var designer = new Stimulsoft.Designer.StiDesigner(null, "StiDesigner", false);
    // designer.report = report;
    designer.renderHtml("designerContent");
  }
  loadprev() {
    var viewer = new Stimulsoft.Viewer.StiViewer(null, "StiViewer", false);
    // viewer.report = report;
    viewer.renderHtml("designerContent");
  }
}
```